Establishing and Managing Trust Relationships in Azure Entra ID
How can we establish the truest relationship between two different organizations that are using Azure Entra ID?
Can users of "B" Organization authenticate using "A" Organization's Azure Entra ID if a trust relationship is already established between A and B? If yes, how can we achieve this?
Can a single Azure Entra ID be used if it has a one-to-many trust relationship with other organizations for Single Sign-On?

I believe you can using the Entra id > Trusts setup. I don't have snapshot of Entra admin console, but you can refer the below:
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/identity/trust-domain-options/
Through the registered app maintained by OrgA that OrgB user would access, OrgB user will be redirected to their IDP for authentication when they enter the Email or agreed unique id.
